# config JUnit tests in Spring Boot with @EnableAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test

my server is like this

```java
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication server = new SpringApplication(Server.class);
        server.setShowBanner(false);
        server.run(args);
    }
}
```

and my test config is like this

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Server.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Test
    public void test1(){
        int countRow = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select count(*) from basic_auto_brand;",Integer.class);
    }
```

and I will get the error:

```
10:35:28.719 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@6fd02e5] to prepare test instance [com.nwche.test.MyTest@5700d6b1]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not build an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration.
```

Comment: This works fine for me without any changes. Your issue must be in some other part of your code/setup that you're not showing. Maybe post the pom.xml?

Comment: I notice that you don't seem to have included the `@Configuration` annotation on your application main class. Although if you're on a newer version of Spring Boot, then you can replace your `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoconfiguration` with a single `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Are you certain that the `spring-boot-starter-test` module is configured as a test dependency in your project?

Comment: Could you please provide more of the stack trace?